# What is the reason to close connection right after request and open new one for new request?

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I do not understand why I must close a gRPC channel for each request?
Can some one explain it? I get used to have pool off connections for HTTP1.1

Why not to create a channel and use it for each request?

```
request = 'here goes request init'
for i in range(1000):
    with grpc.insecure_channel(host) as channel:
         stub = test_pb2_grpc.TESTStub(channel)
         response = stub.QueryEcho(request)
```

I'd like to have smth like this:

```
ch = grpc.insecure_channel(host)
stub = test_pb2_grpc.TESTStub(channel)
for i in range(1000):
    response = stub.QueryEcho(request)
```

Does it mean that for each request with channel close we will create new TCP session?